# What is the reasoning behind the claim that `Canonical Domain Name rule does not work across different sub domains`?

Tags: iis

Link: https://www.tekcent.com/articles/2013/a-better-canonical-domain-name-rule-for-iis/

The author claims that `The default Canonical Domain Name rule in IIS doesn't work very well. The generated rule doesn't work across different sub domains`.

To test this I created 2 websites-

Website1 has 2 bindings: `xx1.mydomain.com`; `xx2.mydomain.com`

Website2 has 2 bindings: `yy1.mydomain.com`; `yy2.mydomain.com`

Then I added the Canonical Domain Name rule to both so they the request get redirected to the 2nd url.

[image]

Entering `xx1.mydomain.com` in the browser takes me to `xx2.mydomain.com`

Entering `yy1.mydomain.com` in the browser takes me to `yy2.mydomain.com`

This works as expected. What has the author mention that - The generated rule doesn't work across different sub domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the link you provided. I can share my understanding with you and hope it can be helpful to your confusion.

The author's website has multiple bindings and he can access the website via `localhost`, `staging.tekcent.com`, `tekcent.com` etc as the hostname in the URL for different stages (localhost, dev, staging and production); while The canonical domain name is only required in production, so the author only wants requests from `tekcent.com` to be redirected to the production site. Create a canonical domain name rule in IIS, which by default generates a condition like this:

```
<conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.tekcent\.com$" />
</conditions>
```

Any request that is not `www.tekcent.com` will be matched successfully, including any request from `localhost` or `staging.*`, and then redirected. But this is not the effect the author wanted. So the author made some changes to the rules.

Your test doesn't contradict the point he made, the default canonical domain name rules work. If your website 1 works on localhost, it can also be accessed through `localhost`. According to the default rules, when you visit `localhost`, it will also be taken to `xx2.mydomain.com`,
If you don't want to follow this rule when accessing from `localhost`, then you need to change the rule to check for an exact match on `xx1.mydomain.com`.